# How to loop sound in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I tried below code to play a sound in JavaScript for certain times but with no success, the sound plays just once, what is the problem?

```
for(var i = 0; i < errors; i++){
    PlaySound3();
}
```

Function:

```
function PlaySound3() {
    var audioElement = document.getElementById('beep');
    audioElement.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
    audioElement.autobuffer = true;    
    audioElement.load();
    audioElement.play();
};
```

HTML code:

```
<audio id="beep">
    <source src="assets/sound/beep.wav" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
```

Comment: I think essentially you aren't waiting for the sound to finish. The for loop runs very quickly, and you only hear the last one. Try waiting a little after "PlaySound" or using an event to detect when it's finished playing.

Comment: what's your suggestion? how to make a delay between sounds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to play the sound infinitely use the attribute [`loop`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_loop.asp) in the tag audio :

```
<audio id="beep" loop>
   <source src="assets/sound/beep.wav" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
```

**Edit**

If you want to stop the loop after 3 times, add an event listener :

HTML:

```
<audio id="beep">
   <source src="assets/sound/beep.wav" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
```

JS:

```
var count = 1
document.getElementById('beep').addEventListener('ended', function(){
   this.currentTime = 0;
   if(count <= 3){
      this.play();
   }
   count++;
}, false);
```

Comment: I want to loop the sound just for certain times not forever

Comment: When you want to stop the loop, change the attribute 'loop' to false with javascriptp.

Comment: I want to stop looping for example after sound plays for 3 times, how can I know that sound play for 3 so I set `track.loop = false` ?