# Iterating through HTML5 audio files

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, audio

My goal is to iterate through an array, take the value of each element of the array as a key
and play a sound clip associated with that value.  The final result desired is to sequentially
play the sound clips, in the order of their  keys in the array.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
//there are addresses associated with the color sound values 

function playSound(soundValue){
  $sound.src = soundValue;
  $sound.load();
  $sound.play();
}

function playGame(){
  simonSays = [0,1,2,3];

  var soundOptions = {
    0: yellowSound,
    1: redSound,
    2: blueSound,
    3: greenSound 
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < simonSays.length; i++){
    var callSound = soundOptions[simonSays[i]];
    setTimeout(playSound(callSound),1000 );
  }
};
```

This code iterates through the sequence and does wait for the `setTimeout` durations to
finish. I receive this error:

```
 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.
    playSound @ logic.js:72
    playGame @ logic.js:120
    onclick @ index.html:37
```

My understanding is that the audio files are interferring with each other and producing the
error, but additionally there is no delay in the iteration through the sequence that allows 
each file to complete.  I looked at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273552/html5-audio-looping) 
[examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492900/how-to-loop-sound-in-javascript)
 of other efforts to delay media execution
but neither a call to `$sound.ended` or `$sound.onended` were able to prevent the
iteration ahead of the audio file completion. The project will increase the length and order of the array so I need
some way to control the execution of each member of the array.

Can anyone offer any advice?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setTimeout` doesn't delay the loop. The loop causes every audio file to be delayed only one second. The solution would be to put the loop into a function, something like this:

```
simonSays = [0,1,2,3];

var soundOptions = {
  0: yellowSound,
  1: redSound,
  2: blueSound,
  3: greenSound 
};

function playGame(){
  startPlaying(0,simonSays.length);
};

function startPlaying(i,l) {
  if (i==l) return;
  var callSound = soundOptions[simonSays[i]];
  playSound(callSound);
  setTimeout("startPlaying("+(i+1)+","+l+")",1000);      
}
```

Comment: I really like the recursive call but I am still getting an error; when I set the ```setTimeout``` with the call as a string it produces this error: ```Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:14```  When I reference the ```startPlaying(i+1, l)``` not as a string it produces the same effect of cycling through the full range with no calls to the audio file, same as the original problem.  Any thoughts? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I didn't notice that problem. I've edited my post, let me know if it works! It's hard for me to debug this kind of problem because it's hard to reproduce the html you're having.

Comment: Perfect!  It was my problem accurately writing the function call, ensuring that the combination of string and number was sent worked perfectly.  This was a great solution.  Thank you for your time.